# Laravel eloquent where max date equal to past 30 days

Tags: php, laravel

I have this eloquent:

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];
$transactions = Transaction::whereIn('user_id', $users)
            ->where(DB::raw('DATE(MAX(created_at))'), Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();

return $transactions;
```

But it return me this error: `General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select * from transactions where 0 = 1`

How can I get all the users that last transaction equal to past 30 days?

Here is the raw query incase you needed:

```
select * from `transactions` where `0` = 1 and DATE(MAX(created_at)) = ?
```

Table Structure:

`Users Table: id (not autoincrement), name, gender, created_at`

`Transactions Table: id (not autoincrement), user_id (FK), amount, created_at`

My current solution:

Iterate every user and check their max `created_at`.

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you are trying to query exactly, it looks like there is a much more eloquent way to do this? You are querying where the `user_id` is in your array, but what are you trying to do with the date?

Comment: Hi @James. Sorry for my bad explanation. I've tried to query all transactions within those array of user that the last transaction is equal to 1 month

Comment: When you say is equal to 1 month, are you wanting those where the `created_at` date is exactly one month in the past or those that are 1 month or older?

Comment: @James exactly one month.

Comment: Could you provide table structure? simplified...

Comment: @Kyslik I've update my question with simple table structure

Comment: You can't use a grouping function (like `MAX`) inside a `WHERE` clause. In a straight MySQL query, you would need to move this to a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: For example (in Eloquent) `->having(DB::raw('DATE(MAX(created_at))'), Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))` so swap out your `where->` with `having->`

Comment: @Anthony the problem with having i've tried it is: It will return all the transactions that less than a month

Comment: I know this does not solve your problem, but you don't need any foreach (as you mention in comments below) just use collections `unique()`: `$transactions->unique('user_id')` and you get what you want. I have searched some topics that might help but nothing is Eloquent way, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760789/limit-number-of-rows-per-id-in-a-sql-query?lq=1 Also use `whereDate()`..

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks for the heads up! will do check the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this without having to use a `DB::raw()` query.

Try this:

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];
$transactions = Transaction::whereIn('user_id', $users)
            ->where('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->get();

return $transactions;
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but the problem is if user has 2 transactions it will keep showing transaction with equal 1 month. I want to get the last transaction from the user. If the last is != 1 month don't show the transaction.

Comment: @SSuhat so you are only after the latest transaction from each of those users that is one month old?

Comment: correct. Even the user has 100 transactions. I only want to take the latest.

Comment: Do you have to use the `whereIn`, or could you run a separate query for each user and return them as one bulk set?

Comment: @Kyslik limiting the result will limit it for all of the users and only return one result, rather than one for each user.

Comment: I want to get every user data.  I've solution with foreach the user one by one. but i don't think its a good idea because it will slow down my server if the user is big. But if the best solution is iterate the user one by one, i don't have choice to take that way

Comment: There may be a way to do this with `whereIn()` but I'm not too sure how to limit it to only one for each person sorry.

Comment: No problem @James. Thanks for trying to help solve this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now what I tried is that I sorted the table in decreasing order as to evaluate the latest record when it will be group by user Id...

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];
$transactions = Transaction::select(DB::raw('select id from transactions order by transaction.created_at desc as table1' )->leftJoin('transactions','id','=','table1.id')->whereIn('user_id', $users)
            ->where('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))->groupBy('transaction.user_id')
            ->get();

return $transactions;
```

Comment: This should working. But i forget to tell, that my transaction ID is not increment. so using MAX(id) won't get latest id

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do a raw query.

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];
$transactions = Transaction::whereIn('user_id', $users)
                ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->subDays(30)->toDateString())->get();

return $transactions;
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but the problem is if user has 2 transactions it will keep showing transaction with equal 1 month. I want to get the latest transaction from the user. If the last is != 1 month don't show the transaction.

Comment: Have you tried  `->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::today()->subDays(30)->toDateString()) `

Comment: I've tried your way, still i can all more than 30 days (duplicate result).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use whereBetween

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];
$transactions = Transaction::select(DB::raw('DATE(MAX(created_at))'))->whereIn('user_id', $users)
        ->whereBetween('created_at',array(Carbon::now(),Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('Y-m-d')))->get();

return $transactions;
```

Comment: no OP does not, OP can use simple `whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))`, problem he is trying to solve is with duplicates, OP wants only one record per user.