# Limiting laravel query using whereIn

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

So i have a query to make but i don`k know how best to it.
I have 2 class like below:

***User.class***

```
class User {
    function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

***Post.class***

```
class Post {
    function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

and in my controller i want to get posts per User with a limit for each user **NOT for all results**. So here is what i have this in my controller:

```
function getPosts(Request $request){
    $user_ids = [1,2,3,4];

    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $user_ids)->latest()->take(10)->get();
    return $posts;
}
```

So the above get will get me just `10 entries from all` of them yet i want to get `10 for each user` nomatter how many user IDs

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124031/mysql-limiting-rows-per-wherein

Comment: Thanks @PrafullaKumarSahu, is there a way of using a query builder for this, i am not that good in raw SQL

Comment: I will try to rewrite, just after my dinner.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that wld be so kind of you

Comment: I have just converted that question's solution to DB query, let me try to write a raw query for you , that we can convert to DB query after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply limit the relationship with a sub-query:

```
User::with(['posts' => function($query) {
    return $query->limit(10);
}]);
```

Comment: I would have done that but it will return me `User objects with posts` but i want it to return `Posts with User`. 
I am using Dingo API so i want to transform `Post objects`

Comment: Ohh, alright. Gotcha. I don't think the Query Builder can do that in one query. You may have to consider using MySQL for that.

Comment: Found something that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21760789

Comment: Thanks buddy, will try and look at it but am not good with RAW queries

Comment: You can't put limits on eager loaded relationships like this. Say you have 10 users with 20 posts each (for a total of 200 posts). This query will get all 10 users, but it will only eager load 10 posts **total**, not 10 posts per user.

Comment: The limit and take query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but it definitely looks promising to me! Cheers Ahmed!

Answer (score 0):

May be something like

```
DB::table('posts as p1')->leftJoin('posts as p2', function($join){
    $join->on('p1.id', '=', 'p2.id')
})->whereIn(p1.user_id, $user_ids)->groupBy('p1.id')->having(COUNT(*) < 10)->orderBy([id, created_at]);
```

will work for you. for the reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124031)

The query was

```
SELECT user_comments.* FROM user_comments
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_comments user_comments_2
ON user_comments.post_id = user_comments_2.post_id 
    AND user_comments.id < user_comments_2.id    
where user_comments.post_id in (x,x,x) 
GROUP BY user_comments.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 
ORDER BY user_id, created_at
```

Roughly in DB query builder, it will be like

```
DB::table('user_comments as uc1')->leftJoin('user_comments as uc2', function($join){
    $join->on('uc1.post_id', '=', 'uc2.post_id')->andOn(uc1.id < uc2.id);
})->whereIn(uc1.post_id, [x,x,x])->groupBy('uc1.id')->having(COUNT(*) < 3)->orderBy([user_id, created_at]);
```

I hope this is helpful for you and give you good idea to get it.

Comment: Thanks buddy, let me try it. Will update u on whether or not i win

Comment: havent been working ystdy but today i am, Thanks for checking up sir, let me make it work boss

Comment: @Flash in the example query there is `andOn` part , that you may need to add according to your table.

Comment: `return DB::table('posts as p1')
            ->leftJoin('posts as p2', function ($join) {
            $join->on('p1.id', '=', 'p2.id');
        })
            ->whereIn('p1.user_id', $channelIDs)
            ->groupBy('p1.id')
            ->having(COUNT('*') < 10)
            ->orderBy(['id', 'created_at']);`

And am getting this for error, what could i have done wrong:
`{
    "message": "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable",
    "status_code": 500
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193083/discussion-between-flash-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Comment: @Flash check if ‘@chennelIds’ is array or not.

Comment: I am on mobile will be on system in 30 minutes.

Comment: Yeah its an array `$channelIDS` is an array
` ->having(COUNT('*') < 10)` this line seems to be the one with an issue

Comment: @Flash so for `*` you are getting nothing/null, change it to `p1.*` and test.